# When I use dd command it does not write data to USB stick

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, dd

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Sometime when I do a `dd` command to a USB stick it finishes very quickly without actually writing data to USB. I discovered it is actually writing to `/dev/sdb` which is a file and not device in such cases but `fdisk` out points to `/dev/sdb` only.

```
root@localhost:/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd# lsblk
NAME                              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                 8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
|-sda1                              8:1    0 189.8M  0 part /boot/efi
|-sda2                              8:2    0 976.6M  0 part /boot
|-sda3                              8:3    0   1.9M  0 part /app_disk
|-sda4                              8:4    0   1.4G  0 part /
|-sda5                              8:5    0   5.7G  0 part /var
|-sda6                              8:6    0 104.2G  0 part
| |-vg0_vjunos-lv_junos           252:0    0    10G  0 lvm  /junos
| `-vg0_vjunos-lv_var_third_party 252:1    0  94.2G  0 lvm  /third-party
`-sda7                              8:7    0   1.2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb                                 8:16   1   7.2G  0 disk
`-sdb1                              8:17   1   1.8G  0 part
root@localhost:/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd# sudo dd if=/var/third-party/install-media-host-usb-nfx-3-20170106_0834_sushilkd.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
1799+0 records in
1799+0 records out
1886388224 bytes (1.9 GB) copied, 1.04298 s, 1.8 GB/s
root@localhost:/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd# sudo dd if=/var/third-party/install-media-host-usb-nfx-3-20170106_0834_sushilkd.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M ^C
root@localhost:/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd# sudo dd if=/var/third-party/install-media-host-usb-nfx-3-20170106_0834_sushilkd.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fsync
3684352+0 records in
3684352+0 records out
1886388224 bytes (1.9 GB) copied, 4.25185 s, 444 MB/s

root@localhost:/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E38875B6-7CE2-4115-A28B-87BE8974DDF2

Device           Start          End   Size Type
/dev/sda1         1953       390625 189.8M EFI System
/dev/sda2       390626      2390625 976.6M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3      2390626      2394531   1.9M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4      2394532      5394531   1.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5      5394532     17394531   5.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6     17394532    235984375 104.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7    235984376    238484375   1.2G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/mapper/<XXXX>: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/<XXXX>: 94.2 GiB, 101179195392 bytes, 197615616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 GiB, 1886388224 bytes, 3684352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd87c498e

Device    Boot Start       End  Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdb1 *     2048   3684351 1841152   e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
```

Comment: How exactly did you confirm `/dev/sdb` is a regular file? Are you sure the quick finishing wasn't because of data caching? (1.8 GiB may fit in RAM nowadays). Did you invoke `sync` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, i did all these checks to make sure that /dev/sdb is regular file but not actual device. I tried resetting related driver(EHCI) but it did not work.The only way it worked is by resetting the system.It looks like clearcase of driver landing into bad state and later it is not able to mount/map the actual device.

Answer (score 4):

I already have this problem, I did this (without reboot) :  after a sync command, remove your USB stick , delete the device file, in this case sudo rm /dev/sdb . After re-plug your usb stick and you'll be able to write on it again.

Comment: In my case, I had to do a full `sudo rm /dev/sda1; sudo rm -rf /dev/sda` - just the `rm /dev/sda` was not enough. I had to do this after accidentally using `dd` on `/dev/sda` when no sda device was actually there